# How to find all stores that use a particular Model in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

I'm fairly new to ExtJS and in the evaluation phase. I want to take care of data dependency in my system. For example, there is a pie chart showing different fund allocations for a portfolio. I might modify the details of a particular fund, which changes these allocation values. 
Saving the new fund details should re-draw the pie-chart with the new values.
To clarify, the fund details that I modify and the allocation details in the pie-chart are two different models. They do not fit the 'associations' that ExtJS provides.

I'm thinking of a mechanism to 'notify' the pie-chart to re-draw (reload store) whenever I change the fund details. I want to take care of these dependencies at the model level and not at the store level. 
One of the solutions:
1. Each of my Models will have list of dependent models.
2. When a store is modified, go through this list of dependents
3. For each of the dependents find all the stores that are using this model, and ask them to reload.

Step #3 is the problem. Is there a way to get all the Stores that use a particular model.
Or, is enumeration of all Store IDs in the Store Manager my only option?

Thanks!